# Find entities by relation ids in objection.js

Tags: node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I have products and they related to categories

```
categories: {
      relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
      modelClass: `${__dirname}/../../categories/models/category`,
      join: {
        from: 'products.id',
        through: {
          from: 'categories_products.productId',
          to: 'categories_products.categoryId',
        },
        to: 'categories.id',
      },
    },
```

How can I build query to find products by categories ids, without fetch categories than fetch products ids in relation table, is there a way to pass `whereIn({ catagories: [123, 15] })`, or something like this ?

Comment: your question is unclear, could you edit it so that people can help you better